# DSRC and WIFI (LTE/Cellular) in vehicular communication

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo, ns-3

Can NS -2.35 simulate both DSRC and WIFI vehicular communication in the same environement?

If not, is there any software simulation capable of ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veins 5.0 can be used to model wirelessly-networked road traffic (cars, trucks, bikes, trains, pedestrians). By default, Veins 5.0 includes models of DSRC, but it can be used together with projects like INET (for WiFi), SimuLTE (for 4G+ mobile broadband networking), or Veins VLC (for visible light communication). See http://veins.car2x.org/ for more information.

Comment: Hi. I moved with instant veins. Both veins and veins_inet simulations worked fine. then I tried to merge both into a single environment by creating two vehicle types in rou.xml files and add them to mobility. I've heard I have to use only one mobility module in one simulation, so I tried to use either veins-mobility or inet-mobility but it keeps giving me errors. How am I supposed to proceed with.